Is it possible to retrieve resource_account signer out of the module address? move on aptos
I started learning move language on aptos blockchain by solving programming quests on overmind.xyz
This is an example:
https://github.com/overmind-xyz/heads-up/blob/main/sources/coin_flip.move
I implemented init_module function:
fun init_module(admin: &signer) {
        // TODO: Ensure the `admin` signer has enough APT coins for the prize.
        // 
        // HINT: 
        //      - Use the `PRIZE_AMOUNT_APT` constant as the amount of APT to check for
        //      - Use the `check_if_account_has_enough_apt_coins` function
        check_if_account_has_enough_apt_coins(signer::address_of(admin), PRIZE_AMOUNT_APT);
        // TODO: Create a resource account using the `admin` signer and the provided `SEED`
        //          constant
        let resource_acc:signer;
        let res_acc_caps:SignerCapability;
        (resource_acc, res_acc_caps) = account::create_resource_account(admin, SEED);
        // TODO: Register the resource account with AptosCoin and transfer `PRIZE_AMOUNT_APT` amount 
        //          of APT from the admin to the resource account
        coin::register<AptosCoin>(&resource_acc);
        coin::transfer<AptosCoin>(admin, signer::address_of(&resource_acc), PRIZE_AMOUNT_APT);
        // TODO: Create and move a State resource instance to the resource account
        let game_state = State {
                // ID of the next game - IDs start at 0
                next_game_id:0,
                // SimpleMap instance mapping game IDs to Game instances
                games:simple_map::create(),
                // Boolean value indicating if any player has already claimed the prize
                prize_claimed:false,
                // Resource account's SignerCapability
                cap:res_acc_caps,
                // Events
                guess_flips_events: account::new_event_handle<GuessFlipsEvent>(&resource_acc),
                provide_flips_result_events: account::new_event_handle<ProvideFlipsResultEvent>(&resource_acc),
                claim_prize_events: account::new_event_handle<ClaimPrizeEvent>(&resource_acc),
            };
        move_to(&resource_acc, game_state);
    }

And I have view function get_all_games:
    public fun get_all_games(): SimpleMap<u128, Game> acquires State {
        // TODO: Return State's `games` field
    }

Question is how do I get state inside a function if I have only module address? How to get resource account signer here?
